# SQL Azure Standard Geo replication - Promote Non readable secondary replica to Primary

Tags: sql-server, database, powershell, azure, azure-sql-database

For Disaster recovery scenario , I have created a Primary DB and secondary replica using standard Geo replication.

I wanted to simulate the DR / DR Drill so I have used the below powershell CMDLET for terminating the the continuous copy relationship and to promote the secondary replica to primary.

```
Stop-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy -ServerName "S1"-DatabaseName "ActiveGeoReplicationDemo"-PartnerServer "S2"
```

This works fine for Active geo-replication, but throwing error for the Standard geo-replication as below,

> Stop-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy : Friendly termination of an offline
>   secondary relationship is not supported.

I thought the deletion of primary db would promote the secondary to primary automatically and deleted the primary. As expected, with active Geo-replication , the secondary has been promoted to the primary But in the Standard GEO-Rep still the secondary is Non readable.

> So the Question is , How can i promote the non-readable Secondary DB 
>   to primary using Standard geo-replication? ( How Fail-over and fail-back to be done?)

It would be great if i get the power-shell  cmdlets or some references for this.

Answer (score 1):

This example forcibly terminates a continuous copy relationship from the server that hosts the secondary database. (this is the working sample)

```
$myDbCopy = Get-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy -ServerName "t4xl86670k"
-DatabaseName "failover" 
$myDbCopy | Stop-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy -ServerName "t4xl86670k" -ForcedTermination
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn720223.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to force terminate the relationship I believe and to mimic the right DR drill you need to execute this from the partner server. Try:
Stop-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy -ServerName "S2"-DatabaseName "ActiveGeoReplicationDemo"-PartnerServer "S1" -ForcedTermination